# Xcode Universal Storyboard fixed size for Phone but not for Ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I am trying to use the new universal storyboards. Inside of my main view I want to have a box which fills the screen width of all phones (minus 10 px padding to the left an right side).

On the Ipad I want the box to have a fixed size because it would be too big to fill the whole screen.

The height of the box should be fixed on all screens.

How can I do this?

Comment: What iOS versions do you need to support?  Are you using size classes?

Comment: you need only ios8 use Size Classes and below ios8 use Auto Layout

Comment: 8+ are the versions. I use size classes

Comment: size classes with Auto-Layout required for fixing height in all screens